# How to get lat and long from geom column in postgres DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table in postgres DB named "building_footprints".

Please see attached image

[image: Postgres table image]

and running below query to table

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) FROM (
SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features FROM (
    SELECT 'Feature' As type, ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.the_geom)::json As geometry,
    row_to_json((gid, the_geom)) As properties FROM building_footprints As lg
) As f) As fc
```

Query Result is:

[image: Query Output]

I want to convert coordinates `value(coordinates":[[[[530500.00039933,545400.008863266],)` in to lat/long.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT id, the_geom , ST_X(the_geom::geometry), ST_Y(the_geom::geometry) FROM building_footprints;
```

you should have postgis extension installed!

see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57018/get-lon-lat-values-from-a-geography-data-type-in-postgis